# What is the proper way of getting the keyCode from a keyboard event

Tags: javascript

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/keyup?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/keyup) that both `keyCode` and `which` are deprecated.

If both are deprecated, what is the proper way of getting the keycode.

Comment: Eh, says it's deprecated yet the suggested alternative `key` is *Unimplemented*

Comment: Which only works in Firefox and returns the string "Enter" instead of "13" for the Enter key.

Comment: Of which, you're not using FireFox Nightly or Aurora are you?

Comment: Nope, the stable one. On Chrome Canary for example, `key` doesn't even exist on the `event` object.'

Comment: If you're so worried about this my advice is to use jQuery which "normalize" those things, see [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/).

Comment: Yeah, but surely this should be something you should do with vanilla JS without worrying.

Answer (score 4):

you are suposed to use "key" instead of "keyCode".
problem is "key" is not yet implemented. so for now keep using "keyCode".

Comment: `key` doesn't return the key code in Firefox, it returns the string "Enter" for Enter key.

Comment: you are right, it doesn't return the code, but it is not yet implemented, so if you want to do something based on a key press. you should still use keyCode in you code.